# rigged character model 'ripping and warping'?

Tags: texturing, rigging, pose-mode

My apologies if this question has already been answered. I am a complete beginner and do not know the 'term' for it.

I have rigged my character model using rigify but the character is completely being 'ripped' when in pose mode.

hair is stretching, clothes do not move from original position, and eyelashes stay in the same place as if it is 'locked'

Ive tried finding the answers to the solution for a whole day yesterday with no avail. I would at least expect everything to move around as if it is 'one'?
Everything is grped together to the rig being parent.

Any genius' here kind enough to show me the way?

Thank you kindly.

[image]

Comment: Well... usual question: could you upload your file here? Please use this site http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and copy paste the obtained link here (editing your question or in comments)

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=o0OPPEZb" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/o0OPPEZb/)

Comment: Thank you. Added it to post and in the comment section.

Comment: What part are you talking about? Are you talking about the hair? You need to assign it to the right vertex group

Comment: The hair, the top (clothes) and the eyelashes. Not sure if the vertex is the same thing as 'assigning to parent. Ive checked the vertex group and they all exist?